# after press button which perform image processing my App get Crshed

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, opencv3.2

I am creating an app which capture image & show in `imageview`.
after that, I perform features extraction using ORB & matching.
but when I click on the next button my app gets crashed.

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.camscanner, PID: 14872
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create_1(int) (tried Java_org_opencv_features2d_DescriptorMatcher_create_11 and Java_org_opencv_features2d_DescriptorMatcher_create_11__I)
        at org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create_1(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.java:76)
        at com.example.camscanner.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:101)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14872 SIG: 9
Process 14872 terminated.
```

Any one know how to solve this error?

Here gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.camscanner"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(path: ':scanlibrary')
    implementation project(path: ':openCVLibrary320')
}
```

if any one know how to solve this error please comment.

Comment: IMO the error is very clear!

Comment: i new in android studio so can you please explain more?

Comment: post your gradle implementation here

Comment: i posted my app gradle implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think its a dependency problem , try to go to File and choose 
Invalidate crashed / Restart 
and see if this fixes your problem..

if not change (or update ) your dependencies